# Linux VM stuck in Provisioning for last 2hrs - Azure

Tags: centos, azure

I had a CENTOS VM running fine, it was hosting a website.

I captured the image using these instructions, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-capture-image/ The image I created is visible even on the azure management portal.

I have tried to create a new VM using the Image but the new VM is stuck in provisioning for last 2 hrs.

I have tried again to create a new VM using the Image and a Reserved IP, that is also stuck for last 2 hrs.

I have used the azure cli tools to force reboot the servers. They are now past the provisioning stage on restart, however I can't sudo on the servers. I have used the reset password functionality from the azure portal but any attempted login from ssh using thereafter gives permission denied.

Another question is : How can I re-provision my original VM? I can't see it any more using the azure management portal and also using azure CLI tools.

I have asked this question in the MSDN forums too but so far no response

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the guide and it works for me (I created new Centos VM and capture it). I tried login to the new VM from the image and I still have my sudo access. So, the guide is correct maybe you just do something wrong in the process. And also make sure you use the new user that you created for the new VM not the old one from the VM that you deprovision.

For the second question, if you deprovision VM and capture it, the VM will be removed so you cannot access it again